# How do I make `less` output colors?

Tags: command-line, less

When I run a program (for example `grep` or `ls`) without a pager, its output is colored. However when I run it piping its output to `less`, no colors are shown.

For example, this command outputs colored output:

```
grep -r something
```

but this doesn't:

```
grep -r something | less
```

Why? How can I see colors through `less`?

Comment: `grep --color=always "search string" * | less -R` but I tend to use `most` nowadays instead of `less`. ALSO: http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/ is a color highlighter (less works too)

Comment: @alex have you installed `python-pygments`?

Comment: @souravc no I did not install that

Comment: @ales ignoring me are we? >:-D

Comment: Check [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139787/209677) (or [here](https://superuser.com/q/71588/500826)) if what you want is just syntax highlight on `less`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- Commands like `ls` —which auto-detect the colour support— don't find support from pipes
- `less` is set to just display colour codes by default.

Both can be overcome but it's a bit clunky:

```
ls --color=always | less -R
```

This isn't `ls` specific. Many commands that support colour also have an override argument.

---

A slightly more in-depth answer is that `ls` is checking whether or not its STDOUT belongs to a real terminal or not. When you pipe things around, the STDOUT is set to the STDIN of the next command.

You can see this at work [in the `ls` source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c). It's using the `isatty` command (a core POSIX interface) to work out what the situation is:

- Are colours on by default:

  ```
      print_with_color = (i == color_always
                          || (i == color_if_tty
                              && isatty (STDOUT_FILENO)));
  ```
- Do we try to output in multiple columns:

  ```
  if (format == long_format)
    format = (isatty (STDOUT_FILENO) ? many_per_line : one_per_line);

  //...

  if (isatty (STDOUT_FILENO))
    {
      format = many_per_line;
      set_quoting_style (NULL, shell_escape_quoting_style);
      qmark_funny_chars = true;
    }
  else
    {
      format = one_per_line;
      qmark_funny_chars = false;
    }
  ```

`grep` does a very similar thing, unless explicitly overridden, it'll detect colour support, with `isatty`:

```
color_option = isatty (STDOUT_FILENO) && should_colorize ();
```

Comment: My last upvote (reached the limit) for today to support you for 100k. But me and Rinzwind want cake when that happens.

Comment: I downloaded a program with name was ack-grep. when type ack-grep foo , it will search for foo on the all sub directories.So I did ack-grep foo | less, and the colors gone. But seems this program does not support "--color=always", whatever thanks for help

Comment: @alex ack has a `--color` argument: `ack-grep -i select --color | less -R`

Comment: @Oli .........Oh my God........ the only thing that I can say about  your knowledge and help and also power of linux

Comment: @ales he stole that line from my comment >:-D

Comment: @Rinzwind I'd like to say "BWAHAHAAA!" but I didn't even notice :(

Comment: @oli ok but hakermania and me want cake in 1900 rep >:D

Comment: I still wonder how ls does its output. Not the colors, I'm talking how it displays the files in columns to optimally fill the whole width of the terminal, and then the second you pipe it to something, it's a straight list. That's some ingenious engineering.

Comment: @B1KMusic I agree. I agree so much that I found how *how* it works and updated the answer. You can force columns with a `-C` argument.

Comment: For me it doesn't work: `printf "a\nb\n" > text; pcregrep -M --color=always "a\nb\n" text | less -R` highlights only "a", but should both "a" and "b".

Answer (score 4):

If you're interested in colors in `less` more generally, you might want to look at `lesspipe.sh`. See, for example, https://github.com/wofr06/lesspipe.

> lesspipe.sh is an input filter for the pager less as described in less's man page. The script runs under a ksh-compatible shell (e.g. bash, zsh) and allows you to use less to view files with binary content, compressed files, archives, and files contained in archives.

It will also colorize shell scripts, perl scripts, etc. similarly to a text editor, but without the use of any "preprocessing" program to do the colorizing.

Answer (score 0):

@oli's answer relies on you being able to provide appropriate flags to the command that produces the colors.  That can be difficult if commands are buried in scripts and the like, and it requires working out how to provide appropriate flags separately for various commands that know how to produce ANSI escapes when the terminal environment says they can.

@DaveEmme's answer tells you that you can use lesspipe to colorize output from whatever source, but as far as I know it won't retain the color from commands that already produce it when output goes to the terminal.

If you already have a command that works just fine in your terminal, then it's nice to be able to run that command in such a way that color escapes are kept regardless of the output being piped, so you can feed that into `less -R`.

`unbuffer` does this for you.  On debian at least you get it with `sudo apt install expect-dev`.

You can then do:

```
unbuffer [command] |& less -R
```

Using `|&` instead of `|` might be an unnecessary detail, but it means STDERR gets piped to less as well as STDOUT.

Thanks to https://superuser.com/a/1260695/229226 for this.