# How to use `cat` to see the top of a very long file?

Tags: command-line, cat

I'd like to know how to

```
cat my-verylong-file
```

and show it from the top instead of the end. Like the **man** command does.

Comment: For completeness, there is also the `more` command... but since `more` is less capable than `less`, it's very true that "less is more".   Finally there is also `pg` for "page".  You can also use these commands with pipes - eg. `ls -l | less` to break a very long file-listing into multiple pages.  And you could even use `cat my-verylong-file | less`.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that *"By default, man uses /usr/bin/less -is."* (from `man man`).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use `less`, which will show the file from the top, allowing you to scroll through it, just like `man`:

```
less my-verylong-file
```

- *Press <kbd>q</kbd> to exit.*

If you're just interested in seeing the n first lines of a file, `head` may be an alternative:

```
head -n 25 filename
```

will show the 25 first lines of the file.

Same thing for the n last lines of a file with `tail`:

```
tail -n 25 filename
```

Comment: `less` could be used also to scroll very-long outputs of commands. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/482826/566421) is presented an example: `ls -laR --color=always ~/ | less -R`.

Comment: And the command name "less" is a pun on the command name "more" (which it more or less replaces) which in turn was named from the "--More" prompt it gave.  Under MacOS it appears that more is the same binary as less so the metamorphosis is complete :)

Comment: So, More or less the same thing?

Comment: @pa4080: you can set up `less` so `-R` is enabled by default.  See my answer.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach `more` *and* `less`: the same thing :)

Comment: `more` and `less` are not really the same thing. `more` can only go forward, but `less` can also go backward, which is why it is named the way it is.  The `more` and `less` commands can be the same binary, which then examines the name by which it was invoked to determine whether to allow going back.

Answer (score 12):

`man` uses [`less(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html) as a pager by default.  Use it instead of `cat`.  See also [@vidarlo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956631/how-to-use-cat-to-see-the-top-of-a-very-long-file/956634#956634).

#### How to customize `less` to make it even better:

I like to `alias m=less`, so it's just a single-letter command, because I type it all the time.  Putting a `|m` at the end of anything pipes it into a pager.

You could put options like `-iMRj5X` in the alias (e.g. `alias m='less -iMRX`), but I do that with my `~/.lesskey` file.  (See [`lesskey(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lesskey.1.html)).

- `-i`: searches are case-insensitive (unless you use any capital letters)
- `-M`: longer status line, showing line number and file-percentage
- `-R`: allow some control-codes through, so you can pipe colorized commands into less.
- `-X`: don't switch to the terminal emulator's "alternate" screen, so whatever you were looking at will still be there when you `q`uit out of `less`.  (great for man pages after you find the option you want, and want to look at it while typing it.)
- `-j5`: searches put the target line at row 5 instead of the top of the screen.  So you can see context on both sides of your search result.  (Sometimes I change this interactively, by typing `-j40` or something inside `less`, if it's most useful to see context before a search hit).

---

I also bind `.` to `next-file`, and `,` to `prev-file`, because the default bindings are two separate characters which are *much* slower to type: `:n` and `:p`.

---

This is my `.lesskey`:

```
$ cat .lesskey
. next-file
, prev-file
#env
LESS = iMRj5X
```

Run `lesskey` to "compile" it into a `~/.less`.

This probably mattered more 20 years ago, but `less` reads that binary file instead of parsing a text config file every time it starts.

Comment: @Dan: Added a line at the top so this answer can stand on its own as an answer to the question.  I thought that leaving that part implicit would be sufficient given the other answer, but if I have no objection to making it explicit if it was bothering you.